# Error: The target entry-point "@angular/flex-layout" has missing dependencies: - @angular/cdk/bidi

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I was tried to add flexlayout in angular but every time I Did I Got this error Alought I Changed the version of npm layout so how I Can fix this ?

```
D:\angular\Technia-tech>ng serve
- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...Compiling @angular/flex-layout/core : es2015 as esm2015
D:\angular\Technia-tech\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\entry_point_finder\targeted_entry_point_finder.js:40
                throw new Error("The target entry-point \"" + invalidTarget.entryPoint.name + "\" has missing dependencies:\n" +
                ^

Error: The target entry-point "@angular/flex-layout" has missing dependencies:
 - @angular/cdk/bidi

    at TargetedEntryPointFinder.findEntryPoints (D:\angular\Technia-tech\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\entry_point_finder\targeted_entry_point_finder.js:40:23)
    at D:\angular\Technia-tech\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\analyze_entry_points.js:29:41
    at SingleProcessExecutorSync.SingleProcessorExecutorBase.doExecute (D:\angular\Technia-tech\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\single_process_executor.js:28:29)
    at D:\angular\Technia-tech\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\single_process_executor.js:57:59
    at SyncLocker.lock (D:\angular\Technia-tech\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\locking\sync_locker.js:34:24)
    at SingleProcessExecutorSync.execute (D:\angular\Technia-tech\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\single_process_executor.js:57:27)
    at Object.mainNgcc (D:\angular\Technia-tech\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\main.js:74:25)
    at Object.process (D:\angular\Technia-tech\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\index.js:29:23)
    at NgccProcessor.processModule (D:\angular\Technia-tech\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngcc_processor.js:175:16)
    at D:\angular\Technia-tech\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\host.js:146:18

> Blockquote
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by the documentation, need to install 2 packages using

```
npm i -s @angular/flex-layout @angular/cdk
```

Refer to https://github.com/angular/flex-layout#getting-started. Following this solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

Try installing `flex-layout` library by executing the following command:

```
npm install --save @angular/flex-layout @angular/cdk
```

And then import it like this below:

```
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';

// ...

@NgModule({
 imports: [ FlexLayoutModule ],
 //...
});
```